# Magento Send forgot password as texts not reset link

Tags: magento, passwords

I'm new to magento. Currently i'm creating a ecommerce webstore using magento. As you know magento will send a reset password link if anyone forgets his/her passwords. I want the system generated password has to be send to the users not as password resetlink.

Plz help me to achieve this....

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sending plain text passwords in email is a bad idea, but this functionality exists in previous version of Magento.

Answer (score 1):

The current 2 step password reset feature was introduced in 1.6, so you could look at porting the password reset code from an older version of Magento into your site.  We've looked at doing the opposite (back-porting the new method to older Magento sites) and it's do-able.  The current method is much better from a security perspective, so while what you want is possible, it's probably not advisable.